# Java: How to share common application / UI code among several applications

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I have several applications that differ mostly based on resources.  As of now, I'm copying the code around to each application.  This can be problematic.  An example, fixing a bug in one, and forgetting to update to the others.

I don't think creating a JAR is appropriate for this situation, as these are application specific UI classes, (actually android activity classes in specific) including the actual app start-up code.

It may be possible to include these source files into several packages, but then I have the problem that each file specifies a specific package name on the first line.

Most of the code is related to the UI and Activity processing.  (The actual common code is already in a library).  A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576980/including-android-activities-and-their-layouts-in-jar-files).
Are there any elegant solutions to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by going with Android Library projects.  (Not sure of the details, perhaps they are ultimately jars)  Check out details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html), specifically the section 'Setting up a Library Project'.
I basically put in all my activity classes (except for the start-up one) into the library.

For true non-UI bound code, JARs, do seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

A jar is absolutely appropriate for this situation. You should split your application into layers, separating the application-specific classes from the shared code.

Comment: I should have qualified that all utility code is already in a library.  The issue is with all UI-specific (android activities), especially the main start-up one.  These are the bulk of the code and are referenced in the android manifest.  I'll look into adding these into a jar and find a way to keep the manifest happy.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with artbristol.

I also recommend to use Maven and:

- release the common jars to a corporate Maven repository
- declare a dependency with specific versions on these jar artifacts

Like this you don't break applications if you do some incompatible changes.